# Adding class to module block

Tags: theming, blocks

When I use the this code; `<?php $block = module_invoke('locale', 'block_view', 'language'); print $block['content']; ?>`, I get the following output. But I'd like to add another class to ul.

```
<ul class="language-switcher-locale-url"><li class="en first"><a href="/en" class="language-link" xml:lang="en">EN</a></li>
<li class="tr last active"><a href="/ru" class="language-link active" xml:lang="ru">RU</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some trial and error but the following allowed me to get the right format;

```
<?php $block = module_invoke('locale', 'block_view', 'language'); $content =  $block['content']; $content = str_replace("language-switcher-locale-url","language-switcher-locale-url dropdown-menu",$content); print $content;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rendering the content instead?

```
<?php print render($block['content']); ?>
```

That, combined with the [Block Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class) module should at least allow you to add a class to the wrapper, which is the next best thing to overriding the theming of the actual UL.

Answer (score 0):

### 1 Enable debugging

in your `sites/default/services.yml`

```
twig.config:
  debug: true
```

### 2 Clear cache

### 3 enable your browser's HTML comments

in chrome it is something  like `Preferences > Elements > Show HTML comments`

### 4 find out the template used for this block

by looking in the inspector you can find suggestions on how to override this template

[image]

in my case there is a suggestion `links--language-block.html.twig`

### 5 copy original template

either from `core/modules/system/templates/links.html.twig`
or from your themes template directory if you are subtheming

Paste into your theme's `template` directory and name it as suggested

### 6 modify the template

and `addClass` to `UL`

This

```
  <ul{{ attributes }}>
```

becomes

```
  <ul{{ attributes.addClass("my-class") }}>
```

### 7 clear cache again

in your inspector you should see your template and your class

[image]

To find out more about [twig name conventions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions) and [using attributes in templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates)